# page-break in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a print stylesheet for a web application. The application uses Bootstrap v4.1.0

i try all soultion on stackoverflow and i stell cant fixit

the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 student">
                            <p>sdd</p>
                            <p>1000</p>
                            <p>R1f17sdf56</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 student">
                            <p>xxxxx  df</p>
                            <p>1001</p>
                            <p>dfdfg</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 student">
                            <p>sdd</p>
                            <p>1002/p>
                            <p>dfgd</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 student">
                            <p>cvbcv</p>
                            <p>1003</p>
                            <p>vxgsd</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the following css code:

```
@media print{

    .student , col-12{
        /*page-break-after: always;*/
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid;

        display: block !important;

    }
}
```

Required I want print one of col-12 per page

Comment: what do you want to be the result?

Comment: print one of col-12 per page
   <div class="col-12 student">
                            <p>sdd</p>
                            <p>1000</p>
                            <p>R1f17sdf56</p>
                        </div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

row display block will fix problem
.row{display: block;}

```
@media print{
    .row{
        display: block;
    }
    .page-break {
        page-break-after: always;
    }

}
```